# How do I scale my AWS EMR cluster with 1 master and 2 core nodes using AWS auto scaling? Is there a way?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, hadoop2

I have implemented a cluster using AWS EMR. I have a master ndoe with 2 core nodes with hadoop bootstrap action. Now, I would like to use autoscaling and adjust the cluster size dynamically based on cpu threshold and some other constraints. BUt, I have no idea as there isn't much information on the web on how to use AutoScaling on already existing cluster. Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't launch a EMR CLuster in a AutoScaling Group. But you can achieve a very similar goal by delivering your CloudWatch alarms notification to an SQS queue and a script consuming from that queue that uses AWS CLI or SDK to modify the cluster.

Comment: Would try that. But should be difficult. Thanks.

Comment: Not realy... see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/receive-message.html

Comment: Finding it difficult to do this way. I guess the better way is to use spot instances on EMR.

Comment: How can we put threshhold breach notification in SQS queue ?