# Terraform for AWS EMR autoscale

Tags: emr, terraform

Have anyone ever used Terraform to provision an AWS EMR cluster with Auto Scaling Task node?
If yes, please share your experience.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I scale my AWS EMR cluster with 1 master and 2 core nodes using AWS auto scaling? Is there a way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512375/how-do-i-scale-my-aws-emr-cluster-with-1-master-and-2-core-nodes-using-aws-auto)

Answer (score 2):

Currently it's not implemented. There are several issues at github and the first step towards EMR autoscaling has been made by being able to specify the autoscaling IAM role for the EMR cluster https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#autoscaling_role.

You must manage the autoscaling policies by yourself via AWS CLI `aws emr put-auto-scaling-policy` and `aws emr remove-auto-scaling-policy`.

Issue requesting feature for actual EMR autoscaling: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/713